# Exception in Tkinter callback that only occurs in a batch run, and not in a Spyder run

Tags: tkinter, callback, spyder

I wrote a code that displays the results of a dynamic 3D simulation. One of the options is to make a random cross-section through the 3D data for a specific time. I display a certain horizontal slide and it is possible to scroll through the horizontal slices for different depths. After that, the user can use the mouse to specify the points along which the cross-section should be made. After that, the cross-section is plotted, and the date is saved. After closing both figures a new random cross-section can be made.

If I run my script directly from Spyder everything works fine. However, if I start my script as follows:

```
C:\WPy64-3860\python-3.8.6.amd64\python.exe C:\WPy64-3860\script.py
```

I get the following error code:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\WPy64-3860\python-3.8.6.amd64\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\WPy64-3860\Eigen_scripts\hstout161220.py", line 768, in plot_and_save
    cross_sc=cross_section_linestring(da,profiel)
  File "C:\WPy64-3860\python-3.8.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\imod\select\cross_sections.py", line 403, in cross_section_linestring
    return _cross_section(data, linecoords)
  File "C:\WPy64-3860\python-3.8.6.amd64\lib\site-packages\imod\select\cross_sections.py", line 275, in _cross_section
    raise ValueError("Linestring does not intersect data")
ValueError: Linestring does not intersect data
```

This is the piece of code where it goes wrong:

```
    elif plane_id in ['User defined']:
        for ind2 in range(len(time_selection)):
            # Create the start point and end point for the cross section
            Y=np.flipud(np.rot90(Data_4D[:,:,:,time_selection[ind2]]))  #3D data 1 time for scroll slices
            Data_3Dt=Data_4D[:,:,:,time_selection[ind2]] #3D data 1 time for vert cross section

            class IndexTracker(object):
                def __init__(self, f1, Y):
                    self.f1 = f1
                    
                    self.Y = Y
                    rows, cols, self.slices = Y.shape
                    self.ind = self.slices// 2
                    
                    self.im = f1.contour(xcoord, ycoord, self.Y[:, :, self.ind])
                    self.update()
                    
                def onscroll(self, event):
                    print("%s %s" % (event.button, event.step))
                    if event.button == 'up':
                        self.ind = (self.ind + 1) % self.slices
                    else:
                        self.ind = (self.ind - 1) % self.slices
                    self.update()
                            
                def update(self):
                    self.f1.clear()
                    self.f1.contour(xcoord, ycoord, self.Y[:, :, self.ind])
                    self.f1.grid(True)
                    self.f1.set_ylabel('Depth %s' % zcoord[self.ind])
                    self.im.axes.figure.canvas.draw()
                    
                def onclick(self,event):
                    fig.canvas.mpl_disconnect(cid)
            
            fig, f1 = plt.subplots(1, 1)   
            
            tracker = IndexTracker(f1, Y)
            fig.canvas.mpl_connect('scroll_event', tracker.onscroll) #update graph 
            
            xyprofiel = plt.ginput(n=0, show_clicks=True, mouse_add=1, mouse_pop=3, mouse_stop=2)
            #plt.show() 
        
            coords = {"x": xcoord, "y": ycoord, "z": zcoord}
            dims = ("x", "y", "z")
            da = xr.DataArray(Data_3Dt, coords, dims)
            profiel=sg.LineString(xyprofiel)
            
            cross_sc=cross_section_linestring(da,profiel)
            afstand=cross_sc.s
            diepte=cross_sc.z
            slice_data=cross_sc.values
            slice_data_rv=np.flipud(np.rot90(slice_data))
            #plt.close()
            
            fig2, f2 = plt.subplots(1,1)
            f2 = plt.contour(afstand,diepte, slice_data_rv)
            plt.grid(b=True, which='major', color='#666666', linestyle='-')
            f2.axes.set_aspect('equal')
            
            # plt.show()
            # prf = go.Figure(data = go.Contour(z=slice_data_rv, x=afstand, y=diepte))
            # prf.show()
            
            afstand, diepte =np.meshgrid(afstand, diepte)
            xx=afstand.flatten()
            yy=diepte.flatten()
            zz=slice_data_rv.flatten()
        
            np.savetxt(f'{dir_data}/random_slice_{selected_times_list[ind2]}Z_{Para}_{larfilename}.dat',np.c_[xx,yy,zz])
                               
            plt.show()
```

Anyone any idea how to solve this? I can of course always run it from Spyder, but the is not always convenient for me.

Thanks in advance,
Nick

Comment: Is spyder using the same python installation as the one you are trying to run your script with?

Comment: Yes, it is the same installation

Comment: On second thought maybe it isn't. I use Spyder v 4.2.1, and the Python version is 3.8.2. Although that is the WinPython installation I use. I have a Anconda installation as well. Didn't try that one yet...

Comment: Then check if the issue is that your are using different versions of the library `imod` and your code is only compatible with one of them (I know nothing about this library)

Comment: I don't know that library very well either. I just took it from the internet because of the cross section option. I had a lot of problems with this library under Anconda. That's one of the reasons why I switched to WinPy. Maybe the best solution is to write my own cross section routine. I thought to save some time. Thanks for your suggestions.